# Jenkins View/Tab Based Security

Tags: security, jenkins

Does anyone know, if there is a Jenkins plugin to allow View/Tab based security?

We use project based security matrix for the overall security. But we are finding, in certain instances this does not fit all needs. We need to give access to a certain job list and allow users to create jobs, within that view. I know you can add security to individual jobs, but that is too much work. It would be best, if you can add security to a collection of jobs, via a view. I really don't want to set up roles, and filters for just a few odd specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing, but I'm pretty sure nothing like this exists yet.

The closest thing to view based security I've found is the [View Job Filter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) plugin. It does allow you to filter a view based on some limited security options for the user (ex. does the user have read permissions). However, the plugin is deficient in that the additional security filters do not limit the existing view settings. The filters only add additional jobs based on the filter settings. For example, if tell the view to include all jobs with regex `.*Admin-.*`, and then I tell the view via the View Job Filter to include jobs for which the user has read permissions; it will include all jobs that start with Admin- AND it will include all jobs for which the user has read permissions. I want the plugin to limit the jobs that start with Admin- based on the read permissions for the user (e.g. display a subset of the Admin jobs).

The [Sectioned View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sectioned+View+Plugin) has on its To-Do list to

> Add security matrix for each view (like Project-Based Matrix Security) - not sure about this one. I think just using the existing project-based security matrix would be better. The sections just need to respect those permissions. See the other to-do item on this topic.

but this has not been completed yet.

Comment: I have yet to test it. But I think there is a solution using Cloudbees Folder plugin.I beleive it uses inheritance, so whatever security defined on the folder should apply to all jobs inside the folder. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin